# Graphics Plotting ggplot

Tags: ggplot2

I'm trying to make a grid in ggplot to plot 4 graphs, as if it were a basic pair (mfrow = c (2,2)). However, I can not execute the code. I have already tried with gridExtra and cowplot with the functions plot_grid, grid.arrange, ggplot2.multiplot and also tried with the multiplot function. The error that appears is as follows:

Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (8598): alpha, x, y, group

Answer (score 0):

```
gridExtra::grid.arrange(ggplot(),ggplot(),ggplot(),ggplot(), nrow=2)
```

produces

[image]

you may want to debug your code for each individual plot first.